# Google Charts Datatable filtering on date

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am trying to find all rows for a particular year. The year is a type of `string` but the cell is type of `date`.

gDataTable:

```
business_id   date          severity
c02facce08ba  Dec 13, 2018  Critical
```

Here is my code thus far:

```
var yr = 2016,
    tl = gDataTable.getFilteredRows([{column: 1, value: yr.toString()}]);
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Type mismatch. Value 2016 does not match type date in column index 1
```

I understand that the value types need to be the same but I can't find a way to filter on just the year of the date column data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of providing the `value` property,
you can use a `test` function.

the function should return `true` for the rows that should be included in the filter.
then, just compare the year value of the date.

```
var yr = 2016;
var tl = gDataTable.getFilteredRows([{
  column: 1,
  test: function (value) {
    return (value.getFullYear() === yr);
  }
}]);
```

Comment: Perfect. Works.

Answer (score 0):

Try filtering using `minValue` and `maxValue` for the date column:

```
minD = new Date(yr, 0, 1)
maxD = new Date(yr, 11, 31)
tl = gDataTable.getFilteredRows([{column: 1, minValue: minD, maxValue: maxD}]);
```